# R: 2 colours in ggplot, 1 for boys, 1 for girls

Tags: r, variables, colors, ggplot2

I'm making a graphic for my data, but I'm struggling with the colours of my plot.
It's a polynomial multilevel model and this is what I got so far:

```
i1 <- ggplot(MPTech,aes(x=PhDTech.Meetmoment,y=PhDTech.Interest,group=PhDTech.Geslacht))
i2 <- i1 + geom_smooth(method="lm",formula= y ~ poly(x,5))
i2
```

`PhDTech.Geslacht` is a categoric variable with two category's (boys & girls). I got two lines, 1 for the boys and 1 for the girls, both in blue with grey.

Is it possible to get a blue line for the boys and a pink one for the girls?

Comment: See http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_manual.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, off course that's possible. Just add:

```
scale_color_manual("Geslacht", values=c("blue","pink"))
```

to your `ggplot` code & change `group=PhDTech.Geslacht` to `color=PhDTech.Geslacht`.